# How do I collect values from a vertex used in a traversal?

Tags: gremlin

I want the details of a vertex along with details of vertices that are joined to it.

I have a group vertex, incoming 'member' edges to user vertices. I want the details of the vertices.

`g.V(1).as('a').in('member').valueMap().as('b').select('a','b').unfold().dedup()`

```
==>a=v[1]
==>b={image=[images/profile/friend9.jpg], name=[Thomas Thompson], email=[me@thomasthompson.co.uk]}
==>b={image=[images/profile/friend13.jpg], name=[Laura Tostevin], email=[me@lauratostevin.co.uk]}
==>b={image=[images/profile/friend5.jpg], name=[Alan Thompson], email=[me@alanthompson.co.uk]}
==>b={image=[images/profile/friend10.jpg], name=[Laura Bourne], email=[me@laurabourne.co.uk]}
```

Ideally what I'd want is:

`{label: 'group', id=1, name='A Group', users=[{id=2, label="user",name=".."}, ... }]}`

When I tried a `project`, it didn't like me using 'in'

`gremlin> g.V('1').project('name','users').by('name').by(in('member').select())
groovysh_parse: 1: unexpected token: in @ line 1, column 83.
   'name','users').by('name').by(in('member`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `in` is a reserved keyword in Groovy you must use the verbose syntax `__.in`

try:

```
g.V('1').project('name','users').by('name').by(__.in('member').valueMap(true).fold())
```

Answer (score 3):

To get your preferred output format, you have to join the group's `valueMap()` with the list of users. On TinkerPop's modern toy graph you would do something like this:

```
gremlin> g.V(3).union(valueMap(true).
                        by(unfold()), 
                      project('users').
                        by(__.in('created').
                           valueMap(true).
                             by(unfold()).
                           fold())).
                unfold().
                group().
                  by(keys).
                  by(select(values))
==>[name:lop,id:3,lang:java,label:software,users:[[id:1,label:person,name:marko,...],...]]
```

Mapping this to your graph should be pretty straight-forward, it's basically just about changing labels.

Comment: looking interesting, I'll have a play with that query, thanks